# TypeScript A<B> as function return type

Tags: typescript, mongoose

What does `Model<IAlbum>` mean in the following function.

```
export const getAlbumModel = (): Model<IAlbum> => {
  
};
```

I couldn't find anything in the docs regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that your function returns an object which is an instance of the generic class `Model` with type parameter `IAlbum`.

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html
and https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html